# Transferring contents of HTML list to text

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, list, xpath

How can this be done? The .InnerText Property (when used on the containing `div` element) is giving me the html only. Is it possible to iterate through all the `li` elements contained and extract their values?

Comment: Is this XHTML (well-formed XML document)? If yes, there exists an elegant solution.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - Doctype is HTML 5 and it is valid code.

Comment: This is a good question (+1 from me), and I believe that my answer provides you with a better alternative than the rest of the answers to your question. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - Elegant solution indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to iterate through all
>   the li elements contained and extract
>   their values?

**From comment of the OP**:

> Doctype is HTML 5 and it is valid
>   code. – Radu

**In this case one can just use the following XPath expression**:

```
div//li//text()
```

This selects all text nodes that are descendents of all `li` elements that are descendents of any `div` element that is a child of the current node.

Using an XPath expression to select nodes in an XML (and HTML5 is well-formed XML) is the recommended, most straightforward and more reliable way than doing this with difficult to construct, difficult to test and difficult to understand and maintain regular expressions.

**Here is a complete code example**:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class TestXPath
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html5Text =
@"<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(html5Text);

        string xpathExpr = @"/*/*/div//li//text()";

        XmlNodeList selection = doc.SelectNodes(xpathExpr);

        foreach (XmlNode node in selection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
        }

    }
}
```

**when the above application is executed, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTML Agilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if this should be done at server side.

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//ul[@id=\"myId\"]/li");
List<string> items = new List<string>();
foreach (var node in nodes)
    items.Add(node.InnerText);
```

**Update**

A jquery script that does the same (for the client side):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertUlToText(ulID)
    {
        var text = '';
        $('#' + ulID + ' li').each(function() {
          text += $(this).html() + '\r\n';
        }
        return text;
    }
</script>
```

Usage:

```
var textList = convertUlToText('myId');
```

Comment: Very interesting. Will this work if the ul is appended using javascript?

Comment: @jgauffin - Even if doing element.InnerText returns the html contents successfully?

Comment: check my updated example if you want a client side script. It's not very clear what you are trying to do and therefore quite hard to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry, as I explained to stephen776, this has to be done server-side. +1 for effort

Comment: The first part of my answer **is** server side

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have list in a separate variable(you've extracted it), and there's nothing between **/li** and next **li**:

```
string[] sep = {"</li>"};
foreach (string s in html.Replace("<li>","").Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None)) 
//do something with s
```

A simple console app as for testing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = "<li>123</li><li>456</li>";
            string[] sep = {"</li>"};
            foreach (string s in html.Replace("<li>","").Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None)) 
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work but it has the same issues as vlad's solution. I may end up doing this even though it's technically not the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

you could always 'brute-force' it with a simple `regEx`, or split the string based on beginning / ending tags

Comment: I've been conditioned to never use regex to parse html, always ends in tears.

Comment: Even though I tend to agree with you Radu, and gave you +1 on your comment, I still tend to use RegEx for parsing HTML, and spend a lot of time crying...

Answer (score 0):

if possible I would use jQuery to loop through the UL and return the values of each LI. Something along these lines...

```
$('li').each(function () {

    alert($(this).html());

});
```

Of course, if u need these values server side, some sort of ajax call to a page method or web service would be needed.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately. I've tried calling a page method but it doesn't work in my case since I need to use some headers that are generated server side. Apparently if I try to pass those through an AJAX called they are simply ignored.

Comment: @Radu How about a simple asmx web service instead of a page method?

Comment: I haven't tried it but do you think that'll allow me to pass special headers? I'm trying to display a file download dialog for a dynamically generated file and I'm putting these headers on my request: `.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=output.txt")` and `.AddHeader("Content-length", fileLength)`. I don't think an asmx service will help because I think the problem is the AJAX request itself.

Comment: @Radu i see... Im not sure if the web service will help. There are jQuery plugins for file downloads...here is one that I found http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/ Maybe that would be of some help.